# How to create Dataset (not DataFrame) without using case class but using StructType?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I create Dataset using `StructType`?

We can create a `Dataset` as follows:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val personDS = Seq(Person("Max", 33), Person("Adam", 32), Person("Muller", 
62)).toDS()
personDS.show()
```

Is there a way to create a `Dataset` without using a case class?

I'd like to create a `DataFrame` using a case class and using `StructType`.

Comment: are you perhaps thinking of DataFrame? It's an alias for Dataset[Row] in spark2, and can be created using StructType to specify a schema

Comment: DataFrame = Dataset[Row], so if you know how to create DataFrame, you know how to create a dataset :)

Comment: @T.Gaweda ,if you see this method "spark.createDataset" there is no option can pass "StructType" and if you are trying to create Dataset using DataFrame still you need case class

Answer (score 7):

If you know how to create DataFrame, you already now how to create Dataset :)

```
DataFrame = Dataset[Row].
```

What it means? Try:

```
val df : DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(...) // with StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val ds : Dataset[Row] = df; // no error, as DataFrame is only a type alias of Dataset[Row]
```

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting question in a sense that I don't see a reason why one would want it.

> How can I create Dataset using "StructType"

I'd then ask a very similar question...

> Why would you like to "trade" a case class with a `StructType`? What would that give you that a case class could not?

The reason you use a case class is that it can offer you two things at once:

1. Describe your schema quickly, nicely and type-safely
2. Working with your data becomes type-safe

Regarding 1. as a Scala developer, you will define business objects that describe your data. You will have to do it anyway (unless you like tuples and `_1` and such).

Regarding type-safety (in both 1. and 2.) is about transforming your data to leverage the Scala compiler that can help find places where you expect a String but have an Int. With `StructType` the check is only at runtime (not compile time).

With all that said, the answer to your question is "Yes".

You can create a Dataset using `StructType`.

```
scala> val personDS = Seq(("Max", 33), ("Adam", 32), ("Muller", 62)).toDS
personDS: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Int)] = [_1: string, _2: int]

scala> personDS.show
+------+---+
|    _1| _2|
+------+---+
|   Max| 33|
|  Adam| 32|
|Muller| 62|
+------+---+
```

You may be wondering why I don't see the column names. That's exactly the reason for a case class that would not only give you the types, but also the names of the columns.

There's one trick you can use however to avoid dealing with case classes if you don't like them.

```
val withNames = personDS.toDF("name", "age").as[(String, Int)]
scala> withNames.show
+------+---+
|  name|age|
+------+---+
|   Max| 33|
|  Adam| 32|
|Muller| 62|
+------+---+
```

Comment: I Agree  @jacek-laskowski with  you that  case class has benefit over StructType, but my motivation for asking this was , i was creating DataFrame for any  data just defining schema for that data in conf and i was building StructType dynamically, based on conf  schema, i was thinking same if can achieve through dataset

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can create the Dataset with a StructType:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("name", StringType, true),
  StructField("age", IntegerType, true)
))

val data = Seq(
  Row("Max", 33),
  Row("Adam", 32),
  Row("Muller", 62)
)

val personDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  schema
)

val yourDS = personDF.as[(String, Int)]

yourDS.show()
```

```
+------+---+
|  name|age|
+------+---+
|   Max| 33|
|  Adam| 32|
|Muller| 62|
+------+---+
```

`yourDS` is a `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, Int)]`.

The `personDS` in your question is of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Person]`, so this doesn't quite give the same result.

See [this post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/dataset-tods-createdataset-advantages/) for more info on how to create Datasets.