# Why eclipse thinks df.as[CaseClass] as an error in Scala Spark program?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, scala-ide

I'm trying to convert a dataframe to dataset using the syntax

```
case class Schema(...)
val ds = df.as[Schema]
```

So my code looks like

```
case class Rule(rule_on: String, rule_operator: String, rule_value: Int, rule_name: String)
val rules_ds = rules_df
   .select("rule_on", "rule_operator", "rule_value", "rule_name")
   .as[Rule]
```

But eclipse is highlighting `.as[Rule]` as error. Screen shots of the same as below.
[image: Error Screen-Shot]

How to resolve this issue? I know its not a Scala issue, as it works on command line.
**Environment (as in Eclipse):**

- Scala - 2.11.11
- Spark - 2.4.0
- JRE   - 1.8

Comment: have you tried to define your case-class top-level, especially out of `main`?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth, thanks that worked. I'm new to Scala, need to know a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Raphael Roth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138523/raphael-roth) (in comments) I defined case class outside main method and it works like charm.
 Also other solution (*without using case class*) is to typecast the dataframe to dataset as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val ds: Dataset[Row] = df
```

The above solution was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286042/3454743)